# umask base permissions on usb drive

Tags: permissions, arch-linux, umask

On linux, the base permission for a file is 666 and for directories, it is 777. With a umask=022, new files and directories have permissions 644 and 755 respectively.

When I mount a usb drive with umask=022, new files and directories both have permissions 755. Why is that so?

Comment: You could simply have had a look at the man page for `mount` (8)...

Comment: Sorry about the close vote, I somehow clicked on the wrong tab.

Answer (score 0):

On a vfat file system no real unix rights are stored. Thus `umask` blocks from the maximum rights possible. If a file is created then the creating process usually does not set execute bits but the file system cannot store this information (thus has to assume that these bits are set).

You can use `dmask` and `fmask` to set different values for files and directories. But you will not be able to execute files (directly) then.